# add text to dojo chart (in this case scatter chart)

Tags: javascript, dojo, dojox.charting, dojox.gfx

I want to add custom text to my (scatter) chart. I could netiher find an example nor any other appropriate dojo function for that.

By now I have a tooltip for each point of my scatter chart, but I'd rather like to have a label for it.

Any idea?

Thanks!

Comment: you want to add a permanently visible label for each point on the chart?

Comment: @TedPrz yes, I want to name the points, so that I don't have to hover over the points for the tooltip.

Comment: as far as I know, you can only add labels on the x and y axes for specific values, or labels to a pie chart, but I think what you're looking for doesn't exist

Comment: ok, thank you...what a pity :( would be also useful for bar charts to write the exact y value of every bar on the bar itself...

Comment: I think that this is something that may come along with dojo later on, I know I've read it in a sitepen tutorial before, cant remember which right now. If I were you, with no other solution available, I would just overlay some divs where your bars/columns are with text content of some sort, (you should be able to figure out where exactly to place them from your chart data).

Answer (score 0):

You need to upgrade to dojo 1.9.7 at least to use this answer:
First of all, You have to set a new option: "labelStyle: 'outside'". This position the text uppon the circle in case the label width is larger than than the circle.
The next option to use is:

labelFunc: function(value){
        return value.text;
    }
This function tells the Chart which label to display.
I updated the fiddle example: Updated JSFiddle